# C# - How to retrieve a value if you know the link text

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

Here is the element I am using:

> `<option value="50418019731">44</option>`

I know the "44" but am trying to get the value from the code. I have heard that you can use Selenium Web Driver but haven't found anything this specific. This value is static, so not dynamic.

My idea is to retrieve all value="50418019731" by knowing the "44"

EDIT:
For more context. I am trying to gather data from a website. The website doesn't allow you to download their source code in C# so I am working with the page's. Elements. The web page comes back "Forbidden" when I use `client.DownloadString("WebPage");` method

Comment: Can you give a little more context to this project? Selenium is typically used to automate a web browser, reading and parsing HTML is probably more suited to HTMLAgility.

Comment: Also, how do you want to retrieve your data? With JS?

Comment: I am aiming to use C# to automate the collection of the web page data, but if it can be done another way I am open to suggestions

Comment: What do you mean `download their source code`? From what you've said it sounds like you'd just navigate to the page with a web browser control of your choice and then use HTMLAgility to parse the HTML. Selenium would only be needed if you wanted to interact with that page such as filling out a form and submitting it.

Comment: Just use `XDocument` to retrieve your data from `html string`

Comment: I have used been trying to do client.DownloadString(WebPage); to download the html code. But I receive a "Forbidden" message when attempting it.

Comment: You want to retrieve value 50418019731 in string

Comment: Yes, that is what I am aiming to do

Comment: Can i Give you code in JAVA

Comment: Sure, anything will help

Comment: Please confirm, are you want to print value'50418019731' or its all values

Comment: Yes, I would like to store the value '50418019731' on its own

Comment: If you receive a "Forbidden" error I assume this page is behind a login? A website can't prevent you from downloading its HTML content or the browser could not render the page, but they can require you to be authenticated first.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, they must need a login

Comment: Surely you know if they do!? I mean what happens if you browse to your URL in a regular browser, does it show the page and can you inspect the source or do you get redirected to a login? Try it in incognito mode to ensure you're not already authenticated.

Comment: _"Cannot store pages HTML as it requires a login, I receive a "Forbidden" message – Alec McEwan"_, this is different problem, nor related to your qeustion.

Comment: I can freely go the webpage and even inspect the source code in by browser. There is no login screen whatsoever. Anyone can go onto the webpage and inspect the source code

Comment: Any chance you can provide the URL? You've providing conflicting reports.

Comment: here: https://yeezysupply.com/products/mens-suede-military-boot-military-light/?back=%2Fcollections%2Ffootwear

Comment: What you want to retrive in this page

Comment: I want to retrieve the size code. The sizes translate to a unique code and I would like to retrieve the unique code by knowing the size that I want

Comment: Try my code by converting to c sharp

Comment: The website doesn't recognise the `WebClient` as a legitimate browser, add a user agent before trying `DownloadString()`. - `client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");` then `var html = client.DownloadString("....");`

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single line of code;

```
var elementvalue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//option[contains(text(),'44')]")).GetAttribute("value");
```

easy peasy :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, so this code in JAVA

```
WebElement elem=    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[contains(text(), '44')]"));
String ValueText= elem.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(ValueText);
```